# Creating an grid based array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create an grid based array in c++, when I create the grid via console, it comes out fine but when I try to implement it inside an array, it messes up.

```
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<100;j++) {
        cout << j << " ";
    };
    cout << endl;
};
```

When I used to create and cout array grid, it doesnt work the same way:

```
int i,j, img[100][100];

for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
   for(j=0;j<100;j++) {
      cout << img[i][j] << " ";
   };
   cout << endl;
};
```

What am I doing wrong exactly?

This should be the correct output:

`//99 rows of the following code`

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ... 99
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ... 99
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ... 99  
...
x99
```

NOTE: this consoles out fine and writes fine to file, but when I try to reproduce this using an array it gets messed up. mostly shows 0's. I need to incorporate this into an array because I need to modify specific parts of the grid.

Comment: *doesnt work the same way* - what exactly are you expecting? p.s. you can remove the `;` after `}`

Comment: Well, your array is not initialized to any specific values.  What do you expect to see then?

Comment: Just updated the post.

Comment: You are printing the contents of an uninitialized array, so you will get garbage.  I think you are confusing an array index with the array contents itself.  My suggestion would be to read up on arrays - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/ (BTW, you will print out 100 rows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing out values in an uninitialized array. The value of `img[i][j]` is not `j` by default - you shouldn't assume anything about its default state. If you do this to initialize the array then you should get your expected output:

```
int i,j, img[100][100];

for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
   for(j=0;j<100;j++) {
      img[i][j]=j;
   }
}

//then print it out.
```

Comment: If you remove the superfluous semicolons after the closing braces, I'll delete my answer since I believe yours includes a better explanation.

Comment: @Edward I copied and pasted and modified OP's code. Now that I notice the extra semicolons I shudder :p